# How to show ICollection count in jQuery tmpl?

Tags: jquery, icollection

In my POCO model, I have a collection property defined as

```
    public virtual ICollection<Position> Positions { get; set; }
```

Now, in my jquery tmpl, I'd like to show the count of Positions property in a jquery tmpl like

```
        <span class="Position">${Positions.Count}</span>
```

However, it shows nothing (empty) there. I don't get any error either. Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the method like:

```
public virtual ICollection<Position> Positions { get; set; }
public int Total { get { this.Positions.Count(); }
```

in your code

```
<span class="Position">${Total}</span>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. It works. However, I'm surprised that this cannot be done in the template directly.

Comment: that's easy: template source is a JSON element, JSON elements do not call directly .NET code, for the template `Position` is that an object, not a collection, if you want, you can call the javascript member that provides you with the length of an array witch is `length`. `${Positions.length}` but if `Positions` is empty, I don't know how it will handle, you need to check the JSON it self.